# What can I do to ask better questions on Movies & TV?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101660/why-is-there-no-hawkeye-movie) here which is accumulating downvotes. As downvotes are a form of community moderation, I want to know: How could I edit the question to make it better? Clearly, there are things I can improve on. It just isn't obvious to me.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: Improvement points can be specific to this question or Movies & TV in general. Both types are appreciated.

Comment: The first thing to note here that is generally overlooked: asking questions is ___hard___ and quite a skill to ask a good one.

Comment: On a note about the specific question, I personally downvoted because I don't like those sorts of questions. No matter the edit it will always be the same question so I doubt I'd ever reverse my vote on it. This is just my opinion though, some people may really like them.

Comment: Questions about why specific things **don't get made**  are rarely useful even if they are wrapped in a supposed aura of topicality by asking for official statements. These statements rarely exist and this tends to lead to answers which are 
 opinion-based because no official reason exists.

Comment: The answer to your question is "because Marvel didn't want to"....money would be the answer essentially but it's doubtful anyone would actually say that quite so blatantly.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot 1. I have learned that asking questions is hard and am not "overlooking it" the way I understand your comment. 2. Your downvote is fair! I don't mind it.

Comment: @Paulie_D So you are saying "Why isn't there...?" questions are "bad" regardless of the reasoning behind why there should be ...? And you are also saying the answer to "Why isn't there...?" is always/usually money? Unfortunately, some things obvious to others just aren't obvious to me...

Comment: @iCom the answer to why any business does or does not do anything is always "because they think they'll make more money".

Comment: @iCom For point 1 that wasn't necessarily directed at you but just a general point/observation.

Comment: @OrangeDog I wouldn't want to use a word as strong as "always." For example, will their be a fourth film installment in the *How to Train Your Dragon* franchise? No, it was intended as a trilogy. Will a fourth film be profitable? Probably.

Comment: @iCom if they think they’d make more money with HTTYD4 than with something else, then they will definitely make it

Comment: @OrangeDog I'm trying to say that there are more factors in making a movie than "money."

Comment: @iCom a good method would be look at the questions (and answers) that have highest votes here. so you'd get an idea

Comment: @Vishwa True, that's definitely good advice. Is this a method that new users (like me) can most efficiently take away from?

Comment: @iCom everybody can learn from it bruv :)